# How to work with Spring Boot + Angular under Firebase Authentication?

Tags: angular, firebase, spring-boot

I've been using Spring Boot and Angular without any issues so far. Except when it comes to [`signInWithRedirect()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices) which is, apparently, [*"preferred on mobile devices"*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin).

The problem is that `signInWithRedirect()` does not seem to work well if the web-application runs on localhost. This appears to be connected to the cross-origin requests when it comes to how Firebase Authentication, or rather AngularFire, works under the hood inside a browser.

Using an emulator will break the JWT validation on Spring Boot resulting in a HTTP 401:

> `JwtAuthenticationProvider: Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid`

We can make it work locally by buildng the app and host it usint the Firebase Hosting Emulator in combination with the Authentication Emulator.

Now the `signInWithRedirect()` will work, but the next problem is that my Spring Boot server now won't be able to validate the JWT tokens.

The reason for that is that these tokens are issued by the emulator, and not not by Google it would seem. I'd have to provide a working `jwk-set-uri` and `issuer-uri` such that Spring Boot Security can validate those:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
          issuer-uri: "https://securetoken.google.com/<project-id>"
```

Is there a way to make this work without having to implement a complicated custom solution for handling the authentication? It's basically a convenience thing but on the other hand it would make testing much easier in the future if the two, Spring and Firebase Emulators, could work with each other seamlessly.

Am I missing/overlooking something here?

I'm not able to find any information on how this is supposed to work. I wasn't even aware that I can make `signInWithRedirect()` "*work*" by using the emulators - it was just a trial & error experiment on my side that made me realize either

1. Run the Angular client inside an emulator and break authentication with the Spring Boot backend or
2. Do not run emulators, hence breaking `signInWithRedirect()`, but let Spring Boot take care of validating JWTs